# How to compute in code what partition Kafka *would have sent (and did send earlier)* sent a message to?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Using a topic and msg key Kafka assigns a topic partition based on:

```
         ... Utils.Murmur2(bytes) % numPartitions ....
```

Now it's simple enough to find murmur2 code. However, murmur2 needs a seed that can change run to run.

My question: given a key e.g. sequence of bytes, how can I compute which partition Kafka *would have sent* the message to with those same key bytes? Assume consistent partitioning.

Armed with this info I can pre-cache some information in different partition listeners as the application bounces.

Answer (score 0):

The seed in Kafka is consistent. You can find it in the source code

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/utils/Utils.java#L394

Therefore, `Utils.toPositive(Utils.murmur2(bytes)) % numPartitions` would be all that you need